# וידבר ה' אל משה לאמר: Same paragraph

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, pentateuch-chumash, sefer-torah, safrus

In almost all cases in the Torah, when G-d's speech to Moshe is introduced with:

> וידבר ה' אל משה לאמר

a new paragraph is begun in the written Torah text at this point.

I'm aware of one possible exception to this: [Vayikra 7:22](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.7.22?lang=he) / [Vayikra 7:28](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.7.28?lang=he) (depending on differing traditions in how to write the Torah).

Are there other examples of this phenomenon? And do any commentaries discuss why there is not a new paragraph here?

Comment: Based on Rashi at the beginning of Vayikra, it means a new קריאה but not a break for thinking it over.  I don't know what that signifies though.

Comment: Consider Numbers 7:4

Comment: In many old texts there were indeed breaks at both and indeed it's arguably a mistake promulgated by Rambam to only have one (see Shach YD 275:2). You are still welcome to ask about any explanations given for a particular set up of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These (7:22, 7:28) are indeed the only two locations in the Chumash where this phenomenon occurs.  It's interesting that based on this discrepancy, there are exactly 100 or 101 places in the Chumash where a פרשה פתוחה\סתומה begins with the word וידבר. See [this lengthy footnote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parashah#cite_note-wayedabber-26) to the English Wikipedia article on פרשיות פתוחות וסתומות which gives some good background on the issue.

A briefer subset of that footnote is the following:

> Ashkenazic and Sephardic Torah scrolls lack an open portion at 7:22 (וידבר... דבר... כל חלב) while Yemenite scrolls have one. Conversely, Yemenite scrolls lack an open portion at 7:28 (וידבר... דבר... המקריב) while Ashkenazic and Sephardic scrolls have one. This situation derives from Maimonides' ambiguous formulation in Laws of Tefillin, Mezuzah and Torah Scrolls, chapter 8.........However, there are actually two places where this is found (Leviticus 7:22 and 7:28), and it is unclear which of them Maimonides was referring to.........How this formulation by Maimonides accords with the Aleppo Codex has been discussed at length by.......Furthermore, all other Tiberian masoretic manuscripts have parashot in both places. Available data on this now-missing part of the codex is as follows: Rabbi Judah Ityah, who examined the codex to answer questions posed by Umberto Cassuto, reported that there were open parashah breaks at both 7:22 and 7:28.........

To date, I have not seen reasons given in the commentaries for why either of those two locations might be missing a parsha break.

It is interesting that by contrast, "ויאמר השם" or "ויאמר אלקים" while tending to have a parsha break more often than not, by far do not receive the same consistency as וידבר.

I believe the breakdown for:

- "ויאמר השם" is 52 at the beginning of a parsha and 26 in the middle
- "ויאמר אלקים" is 9 at the beginning of a parsha and 7 in the middle

Also see [this article](https://basehasefer.blogspot.com/2020/03/our-very-first-blog-post.html) (*my own*) which among other things delves into some related issues of the usages of וידבר and ויאמר at parsha breaks.